# Manwha about a woman who is reincarnated and tries to search for her father

Tags: story-identification, manga

Do you know the name of the manwha in which the female lead is reborn and went to look for her father with the help of a church father who regrets giving her custody to a bad man?

- After rebirth, the female lead still couldn't save her mother, who died without the proper medication, because all the village people had cast her and her mother out.
- This happened because of the bad man who got rejected by her mother. He also happens to be her father's brother, and in her first life, he tried to marry her after she became an adult and caged her in a mansion.
- The church father who always helped the female lead and her mother thought that the bad man would take care of her so he made him her guardian. But in her second life, the church father realised his mistake and helped her escape.
- The female lead met a wonderful woman in the train station who helped her to find her father. Later, the female lead found out that she was going to marry her father and she may have had a son.
- The female lead's father may be a king or duke and doesn't know that her mother, whom he still loves, has died.

Comment: What colour was the female lead's hair? Also, when she was reborn, was she reborn as a younger version of herself in the past, or as a different girl/woman?

Comment: She was caged in a mansion - is this how she died? If not, how did she die?

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark their answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: Does she find her father right away? In other words, is this a story about finding an unknown father, or living with an unknown father?

Answer (score 1):

This may be ***[Searching for My Father](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/7eht5cg/searching-for-my-father)***.

From Baka-Updates:

> The cruel chains of destiny threaten to condemn Louise to a life of slavery. Benjamin, an evil man obsessed with her mother even after her tragic death, takes Louise into his custody, intent on marrying her. Louise tries to escape this horrid fate and awakens eight years in the past. She's set on making things right but is unable to stop tragedy once again. Determined to not give up, Louise embarks on a journey to find her father. What discoveries await her in this fight for freedom? Will her father be the key to her happiness... or her demise?

In her first life, the protagonist, Louise, is stated to have been born without a father, and her mother died when she was just eight years old, so the village chief and her uncle, Benjamin, became her guardian. Benjamin actually proposed to Louise's mother before she passed away, but she declined.

Benjamin was extremely controlling with Louise, and wouldn't allow her to leave his mansion, claiming it was dangerous for her to do so. He was in love with her mother, and wanted Louise to grow up just like her, so that he could marry her when she was older.

By the time she's sixteen, Louise feels like she's living in a cage, and hates the lascivious way that Benjamin looks at her. The story is more implicit than explicit on this point, but the artwork implies that she commits suicide by throwing herself from her bedroom window.

She then wakes up again as her younger self, back when her mother was still alive, and begins studying books in the cathedral library, hoping to find some way to change her fate. She then learns that her father, whom she thought had passed away, is actually alive, and decides to search for him.

There's also a priest in the story, Father Patrick, who serves as a mentor figure for her.

[image] [image]